# Wise But Oblivious

Tags: adjectives

Is there a phrase or word for someone who seems doesn't care about many things because they have had so much experience or have seen a lot. I'm trying to describe a character in a book. Ex. "You are a demigod, walking with a god, on your way to camp to meet others like you. Doesn't any of this come as a surprise to you?" "Eh...I've seen a bunch of weird stuff."

Comment: I like what you already have.

Comment: If you don't want or need the connotations of world-weariness, "unflappable" might be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaded. *Bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something*. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jaded

Or, as Zan700 suggested:

World-weary. *Feeling or indicating feelings of weariness, boredom, or cynicism as a result of long experience of life.*
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/world-weary

Comment: [*Jaded*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded) is the word I would have chosen. But in order for this to be a *good* answer, you need to at least quote a dictionary definition and provide a link to it. Your current answer is unsubstantiated and too short. (Also note that [*world-weary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world-weary) was not offered as an answer elsewhere. What was offered was simply *worldly*. That's a different word altogether. I think *world-weary* is better.)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know those things were needed. I don't think I can edit my answer, so should I answer again in order to add that information? (_world-weary_ was mentioned in the last line of MW's answer.)

Comment: Just click the **Edit** that appears at the bottom of your answer. :)

Comment: Yes, that's good.

Answer (score 0):

Worldly: having a lot of practical experience and knowledge about life and the world. MW

Sophisticated: having an understanding of the world and its ways, so that you are not easily fooled . . . Cambridge

Blasé: apathetic to pleasure or excitement as a result of excessive indulgence or enjoyment : world-weary. MW

Comment: Also satiated...